# jenkins continuous delivery with shared workspace

Tags: triggers, jenkins, workspace, continuous-delivery

#### Background:

We have one Jenkins job (`Production`) to build a deliverable every night.  We have another job (`ProductionPush`) that pushes out the deliverable over a proprietary protocol to production machines the next day.  This is because some production machines are only available during certain hours during the day (It also gives us a chance to fix any last-minute build breaks).  `ProductionPush` needs access to the deliverable built by the `Production` job (so it needs access to the same workspace).  We have multiple nodes and concurrent builds (and thus unpredictable workspaces) and prefer not to tie the jobs to a fixed node/workspace since resources are somewhat limited.

#### Questions:

1. How to make sure both jobs share the same workspace and ensure that `ProductionPush` runs at a fixed time the next day only if `Production` succeeds -- without fixing both jobs to run out of the same node/workspace?  I know the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) might help with some of this but it does not seem to have time delay capability and 12 hours seems too long for a quiet period.
2. Is sharing the workspace a bad idea?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Answer 2: Yes, sharing workspace is a bad idea. There is possibility of file locks. There is the issue of workspace being wiped out. Just don't do it...

Answer 1: What you need is to **Archive** the artifacts of the build. This way, the artifacts for a particular build (by build number) will always be available, regardless of whether another build is running or not, or what state the workspaces are in

### To Archive the artifacts

- In your *build* job, under **Post-build Actions**, select **Archive the artifacts**
- Specify what artifacts to archive (you can use a combination of below)
  a) You can archive all: `*.*`
  b) You can archive a particular file with wildcards: `/path/to/file_version*.zip`
  c) You can ignore the intermediate directories like: `**/file_version*.zip`
- To avoid storage problems with many artifacts, on the top of configuration you can select **Discard Old Builds**, Click **Advanced** button, and play around with *Days to keep artifacts* and *Max # of builds to keep with artifacts*. Note that these two settings do not control for how long the actual builds are kept (other settings control that)

### To access artifacts from Jenkins

- In the build history, select any previous build you want.
- In addition to SCM changes and revisions data, you will now have a **Build Artifacts** link, under which you will find all the artifacts for **that particular** build.
- You can also access them with Jenkins' permalinks, for example
  `http://JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/` and then the name of the artifact.

### To access artifacts from another job

I've extensively explained how to access previous artifacts from another *deploy* job (in your example, `ProductionPush`) over here:
[How to promote a specific build number from another job in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126059/how-to-promote-a-specific-build-number-from-another-job-in-jenkins/15206921#15206921)

If your requirements are to always deploy latest build to Production, you can skip the configuration of *promotion* in the above link. Just follow the steps for configuration of the *deploy* job. Once you have your *deploy* job, if it is always run at the same time, just configure its **Build periodically** parameters. Alternatively, you can have yet another job that will trigger the *deploy* job based on whatever conditions you want.

In either case above, if your **Default Selector** is set to *Latest successful build* (as explained in the link above), the latest build will be pushed to Production

Comment: Thanks, I suspected there was a more standardized way to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not seeing any options to control automatic deleting of old artifacts.  I"m running Jenkins 1.506.  Is that functionality in a separate plugin?

Comment: On the job configuration page, check mark `Discard Old Builds`, then click `Advanced...` button. You can now control individually how long to keep builds and how long to keep artifacts

Comment: Great post @Slav this is really helpful in my switch from fat builds to pipelines

Answer (score 0):

Not sure archiving artifacts is really a good idea.   A staging repository might be better as it enables cross-functional teams to share artifacts across different builds when required by tweaking the Maven settings.xml file.

You really want a deployable (ear/war) as the thing that gets built, tested, then promoted to production once confidence is high with the build.

Use a build number on your deployable (major.minor.buildnumber).   This is the thing you promote to production, providing your tests can be relied upon. Don't use a hyphen to separate minor with build number as that forces Maven to perform a lexical comparison...  a decimal point will force a numeric comparison which will give you far less headaches.

Also, you didn't mention your target platform, but using the Maven APT/RPM plugin to push an APT/RPM to a APT/YUM repo that's available to a production box (AFTER successful testing!) would be a good fit, as per industry standards?