# Jenkins - How to run post-build action without re-running the job?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a lengthy Jenkins job with a failing post-build action.

How can I repeatedly run the post-build action without re-running the whole job?

Comment: What kind of post-build action?  Is it something you could put into a standalone job, triggered off the original job?

Comment: Static analysis of the built objects. I'd prefer not to separate it into it's own job, I hoped there would be a standard way of doing these things, since they're quite common.

Comment: Oh, there may well be!  (I've only been using Jenkins myself for a few weeks...)

Comment: Submit it as an answer if you wish, it might be the only way! How would I access the artifacts of one build from another?

Comment: Ok, I've created an answer below, along with some suggestions on the artifacts issue.

Answer (score 4):

If splitting the job into 2 jobs is not an option, you may consider
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin
(this is pre-installed with Jenkins I believe). This will make the "promotion" steps a separate and repeatable process. You can configure it to run automatically after build, and then manually on demand when needed.

If your post-build steps require access to build artifacts, you will need to use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin to copy the build artifacts to the promotion's workspace.

Another solution is to **skip build step** based on parameter.
Have a **Choice** parameter called *SkipBuild* or something. Set the possible values to TRUE/FALSE, default to FALSE

In your **Build** step, before actually building, check if *SkipBuild* is set to TRUE. If TRUE, exit 0, if FALSE (which is default) then run build command.

This way, automatic Build executions will always run the Build step. But you can also manually run the build and select "SkipBuild=TRUE" to skip the build step and go straight to post-build actions. If you need to skip some post-build actions, you would need to implement this *SkipBuild* parameter there as well.

Careful however as subsequent executions of the build, even with "SkipBuild=TRUE" will still perform an SVN checkout, so your workspace may change.

Comment: Can you explain how the `Promoted Builds` plugin works without having multiple jobs? The documentation only mentions _automatic_ promotion when trigged by another job.

Comment: `Promoted Builds` allows to execute actions on existing past builds. It does retain some information from the past build, such as `$PROMOTED_NUMBER` which indicates which previous build the promotion is running on. However, you still need to use `Copy Artifact Plugin` to access the artifacts from the previous builds. There isn't enough space in comments to explain it, but in short the "promotion" allows you to run pretty much any build and post-build action as you normally would. If you don't want it to be triggered automatically, you can set it `Only when manually approved`

Comment: I have a lengthy explanation on how to archive artifacts here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140580/jenkins-continuous-delivery-with-shared-workspace and another lengthy explanation on the promotions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126059/how-to-promote-a-specific-build-number-from-another-job-in-jenkins . In your case, read how the `deploy job` uses `copy artifacts plugin` and actually do that as your first build step in the promotion job. Then, as a second build step, execute your static analysis

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your build steps are, you might be able to 'skip' them.

For example, my build steps are powershell and windows batch files.

If I want to skip a step I simply add 'exit 0' as the first line of the powershell or batch command.

Be aware this WILL still result in other pre-build steps, like workspace cleanup and scm checkouts being run.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work for because the post-build steps rely on the lengthy build step

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the action is, one crude option may simply be to split it off into a standalone job, triggered by the original.  That way, you're free to re-run it manually.

To share artifacts or workspaces between two jobs, the following plugins spring to mind:

- [*Copy Artifact Plugin*](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)
- [*Clone Workspace SCM Plugin*](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin)