# Best way to use Jenkins to install snapshot on remote machine?

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra

I'm running Jenkins on one server and want to use chef and automatically install a snapshot (including runtime artifacts etc) on a separate server.

Currently Jenkins will use ssh to invoke chef on the seperate machine. Is there a better way?

Maven is also involved in this.

Comment: trigger `knife solo cook SERVER` after build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that majority of "Deploy" type plugins are lacking in customization. We use "Execute" (bash or batch) build steps to trigger deployment scripts on remote machines (written in house, be they Puppet, Chef, or plain bash/batch).

The correlation between builds and deployments is achieved through "Promotions" and explained in detail here:
[How to promote a specific build number from another job in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126059/how-to-promote-a-specific-build-number-from-another-job-in-jenkins)

Comment: using the same thing now :)