# Archiving artifacts in Jenkins and choosing which artifact to deploy to environment

Tags: jenkins

I have curren Jenkins jobs:

```
1. Poll -- Retrieve Latest Tag from SVN
2. Create release and archive it
3. Manual trigger -- Deploy artifact to test environment
```

So 1. retrieves regularly the latest SVN tag (if created), 2. builds the release (.ear files and DB scripts) and stores the artifacts with the "Archive the artifacts" post-build job, and 3. is a manual trigger job where you actually would have to press a button to deploy the release to test environment

My question is, is it possible in build 3. to somehow "select" the desired artifact? Or is it only possible to deploy the latest workspace? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed explanation how to select a **specific** build for deployment

**[How to promote a specific build number from another job in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126059/how-to-promote-a-specific-build-number-from-another-job-in-jenkins)**

In short, you need to combine **Copy Artifacts** plugin with **Promotions** concept