# Running one build per artifact of another job

Tags: jenkins, packaging

I have a jenkins job to create multiple debian packages. Each created package file is archived as artifact of the build. This works well so far.

Currently I am trying to to trigger multiple builds of another job, one for each created package file. This job should install each package in an isolated vagrant box and do some tests on it.

The question is how to trigger the builds. As it would be nice to parallelize the builds it is not easy as doing one build for all packages. The number of packages is not always the same, so it is very uncomfortable to duplicate the job for each package.

Thanks,
krissi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To act on every build of a project, you probably want "Promotions". Read about it here:
**[How to promote a specific build number from another job in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126059/how-to-promote-a-specific-build-number-from-another-job-in-jenkins/15206921#15206921)**

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that solves most of the remaining tasks :) Unfortunately I cannot see how to start multiple builds - one for each artifact. Am I missing something here?

Comment: In the latest version of [**Parameterized Build**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) plugin (which you need to setup Promotions, there is an option **Add ParameterFactories**, select "**For every matching file, invoke one build**"