# Hudson PHP deploy and re-dploy policy

Tags: php, deployment, continuous-integration, hudson

I am using Hudson with PHP to analyse, run-tests etc. But I want to create a deployment policy through which:

1. I can deploy my files on server (Hudson itself installed on server),
2. If code gives some error on production I can roll-back to any particular old builds.

I don't want to use SVN tagging.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Hudson Archiving and Promoted Builds as explained in detail here:
[How to promote a specific build number from another job in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126059/how-to-promote-a-specific-build-number-from-another-job-in-jenkins/15206921#15206921)

Comment: Thanks Slav your solution given me good idea on "How to manage the Deployment" for PHP, thanks alot.