# Execute Shell script from workspace on remote machine after build successful (Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

The scenario is - I have a job A which runs my ant script and packages the artifact's for me.

I am also using parametrized Triggered plug in to Trigger my "Job B" which will deploy my artifact on remote machine.

The job A is working fine and also Job B.

The tasks that i have to perform with Job B are

1. GIT checkout (which contains my deployment scripts) (successfully doning).
2. Copying artifacts from previous build to Remote machine. (successfully doing)
3. Run shell script on remote machine(script present in workspace folder )- Facing issues.

I browsed various plug ins for the same but no one is allowing me to run shell script after , "SCP to remote machine" which is present in Post build action.

I would like to execute the same sequence, however if you guys have any other suggestions please share.

Thanks in Advance.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve my query i used Jenkins SSH Plugin. This provides a configuration tab where i can add multiple hosts and after that used them in my job level configuration.

[Link to Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin)

you get privilege to execute shell script on remote host as pre-build step or post build step.

Comment: @OK999 I am not getting you which answer differs that i posted earlier. can you help me a little. thanks

Answer (score 16):

As part of [**Publish Over SSH**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) Plugin, you can execute a script after the files had been copied over.

- Under **Post-build Actions**
- Add **Send build artifacts over SSH**
- Select a preconfigured server (done in global configuration)
- Select files to copy from workspace
- Enter **Exec command**

  1. If one of the files you copy is your shell script, you can enter it here as an "exec command"

Answer (score 0):

updated the path of [publish over ssh](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh/) it worked for me