# Jenkins Deploy Plugin to Wildfly 8.x resulting in Connection Time Out

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am trying to deploy a WAR file on CentOS 7 from Jenkins to Wildfly 8.2.0 Final using version 1.11-SNAPSHOT (I built it from the fork) of the Deploy Plugin (version 1.10 does not have support for Wildfly and has issues if you select JBoss AS 7.x).

Both Jenkins and Wildfly are on the same box and I have opened all the necessary ports.

I am running into the following issue:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://192.28.26.200:9990. The connection timed out
```

Full stack trace:

```
Building in workspace /root/.jenkins/workspace/DeployJob
Unable to access upstream artifacts area /root/.jenkins/jobs/BuildJob/builds/50/archive. Does source project archive artifacts?
Copied 2 artifacts from "BuildJob » Sample Maven Webapp" build number 50
Deploying /root/.jenkins/workspace/DeployJob/com.sample/Sample/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war under context path somecontext to WildFly 8.x Remote
  The undeployment phase of the redeploy action has failed: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot undeploy deployable org.codehaus.cargo.container.deployable.WAR[Sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot deploy deployable org.codehaus.cargo.container.deployable.WAR[Sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.deploy(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:216)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractDeployer.redeploy(AbstractDeployer.java:234)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:76)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:128)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:107)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:107)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:50)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1776)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://192.28.26.200:9990. The connection timed out
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:103)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.executeOperation(ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.java:51)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.AbstractServerDeploymentManager.execute(AbstractServerDeploymentManager.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.executeAction(JBossDeployer.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.deploy(JBossDeployer.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.deploy(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:212)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://192.28.26.200:9990. The connection timed out
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:130)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:256)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.FutureManagementChannel$Establishing.getChannel(FutureManagementChannel.java:176)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:144)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:115)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:98)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:236)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:141)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:101)
    ... 22 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://192.28.26.200:9990. The connection timed out
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:103)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.executeOperation(ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.java:51)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.AbstractServerDeploymentManager.execute(AbstractServerDeploymentManager.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.executeAction(JBossDeployer.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.deploy(JBossDeployer.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.deploy(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractDeployer.redeploy(AbstractDeployer.java:234)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:76)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:128)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:107)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:107)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:50)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1776)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://192.28.26.200:9990. The connection timed out
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:130)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:256)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.FutureManagementChannel$Establishing.getChannel(FutureManagementChannel.java:176)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:144)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:115)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:98)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:236)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:141)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:101)
    ... 22 more
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Anyone has any idea what could be going on in here? I tried to telnet the IP and port and it worked.

Comment: Is WildFly listening on 192.28.26.200? What plugin are you using as well? It should be attempting to connect to protocol `http-remoting`.

Comment: Yes, WidFly is listening on 192.28.26.200 on port 9990. I tried to Telnet and it worked. I am using the deploy plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin) and have a similar setup as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126059/how-to-promote-a-specific-build-number-from-another-job-in-jenkins. The only difference is that instead of deploying to Tomcat, I am deploying to Wildfly.

Comment: If the protocol is configurable try changing it to `http-remoting`.

Comment: It seems the protocol is not configurable.

Comment: You could try enabling the native management interface which would work on the `remoting` protocol. https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/The+native+management+API?_sscc=t