# Using Jenkins to Deploy to Production Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, svn, jenkins, msdeploy

I have 3 stages (dev / staging / production). I've successfully set up publishing for each, so that the code will be deployed, using msbuild, to the correct location, with the correct web configs transformed - all within Jenkins.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know to deploy the code to staging from what was built on dev (and staging to production). I'm currently using SVN as the source control, so I think I would need to somehow save the latest revision number dev has built and somehow tell Jenkins to build/deploy staging based on that number?

Is there a way to do this, or a better alternative?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Decided to use the save the revision number method, which parses a file containing the revision number to the next job -- to do this, I followed this answer:

[How to promote a specific build number from another job in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126059/how-to-promote-a-specific-build-number-from-another-job-in-jenkins/15206921#15206921)

It explains how to copy an artifact from one job to another using the promotion plugin. For the artifact itself, I added a "Execute Windows batch command" build step after the main build with:

echo DEV_ENVIRONMENT_CORE_REVISION:%SVN_REVISION%>env.properties

Then in the staging job, using that above guide, copied that file, and then using a plugin EnvInject, to read from that file and set an environment variable, which can then be used as a parameter to the SVN Repository URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to identify the changeset number that was built in DEV and manually pass that changeset to the Jenkins build to pull that same changeset from SVN.  Obviously that makes your deployment more manual.  Maybe you can setup Jenkins to publish the changeset number to a file and then have the later env build to read that file for the changeset number.

We used to use this model as well and it was always complex.  Eventually we moved to a build once and deploy many times model using WebDeploy.  This has made the process much more simple.  Check it out - http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/04/16/msbuild-once-msdeploy-many-times/

Comment: Do you have a more detailed blog post regarding your "once and deploy many times" process? Unsure about:
1. Will packaging and the deploying to the different environments use the publish files correctly?
2. Packaging seems to only apply at the project level, so it becomes a pain when my solution needs 4 projects to be published.

Comment: You would need to setup a release orchestration tool to apply the package(s) appropriately.  We use Thoughtworks GO! currently but VSTS has a some really nice features too.  We have 50 pipelines in GO! each with multiple deployable components (ASP.NET sites, SQL Server dbs, Window Services, etc) and it works great.  The following post is a high-level overview of how we create deployment packages.  My blog has many more specific examples as well. - http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2015/04/22/extending-msdeploy-beyond-the-web/